# How to mapping object by RestKit 0.20.x with complicate structure JSON

Tags: restkit-0.20

I'm using Restkit 0.20.x to mapping object from json like

```
{
    "d":{
        "results":[
            {
                "Web":[
                    "key1":"value1",
                    "key2":"value2"
                ],
                "Image":[
                    "key1":"value1",
                    "key2":"value2"
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

My main purpose to manage "Web" and "Image" key. 
I'm trying to mapping object but stuck at "results" key (value of key "results" is a array which has only one element as dictionary).
How to using RestKit to map object in my case ?

My fail implement:

WFSD.h

```
@interface WFSD : NSObject  
@property (nonatomic, strong) WFSResults *results;
@end
```

WFSResults.h

```
@interface WFSResults : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) WFSResult    *result;
@end
```

WFSResult.h

```
@interface WFSResult : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) WFSWeb    *web;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WFSImage  *image;
@end
```

MyController.m

```
RKObjectMapping* dMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WFSD class]];
RKObjectMapping* resultsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WFSResults class]];

RKRelationshipMapping* rsMapping1 = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"results" toKeyPath:@"results" withMapping:resultsMapping];
[dMapping addPropertyMapping:rsMapping1];

RKObjectMapping* resultMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WFSResult class]];
[resultsMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"result" withMapping:resultMapping]];

RKRelationshipMapping* rsMapping2 = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Image" toKeyPath:@"Image" withMapping:imageMapping];
[resultMapping addPropertyMapping:rsMapping2];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor     responseDescriptorWithMapping:dMapping
                                                                                       pathPattern:nil
                                                                                           keyPath:@"d"
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Comment: What did you try and how are you trying to store the data? Show your mappings and data structure.

Comment: i edited my fail implement. Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at removing `WFSResults` from your model classes. Really it's just a list of `WFSResult` objects, so you should look at modelling it as:

```
@interface WFSD : NSObject  
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *results;
@end
```

You also need to look at `WFSResult`, because `Web` and `Image` in the JSON are also arrays. So I'd expect to see:

```
@interface WFSResult : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray  *web;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray  *image;
@end
```

In this way RestKit can create the objects during mapping and then it has an array to store the list of objects.

Comment: Good stuff, and welcome to stack overflow :-) Please accept answers that solved and up-vote answers that helped.

Comment: Can you please tell how to set mapping for nested array of objects? E.g. in the above example `web` is an `NSArray` of  `Web` objects. And `Web` again is the object with some attributes. How can I access those Web attributes?If i do `Web* web = [web objectAtIndex:0]` and then `web.key1` I got null. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How to tell `RestKit` to map object's attributes which is inside the array of objects? Of course I can make relationship mapping but how then add those mapped object to the `NSArray` of this objects?

Comment: @Harry, create a question and give details of what you have and tried.